# Find and replace in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed, replace

How can I write a simple find and replace inside of a `bash` script, but the replace comes from running a PHP script.

For example, I need to find: `{{KEY}}` and replace with the output of: `php -f generate_key.php` in the file `app.config`. Can `sed` accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest something along these lines instead of the sed-based solutions above:

```
KEY="$(php -f generate_key.php)" awk '{gsub("{{KEY}}", ENVIRON["KEY"]);print;}' < app.config > app.config.new && \
mv app.config.new app.config
```

(**Edited at T+20h** to use `ENVIRON` instead of `awk -v VAR=VAL` due to the latter processing escape sequences in `VAL`)

Primarily because it performs the substitution without applying any interpretation or transformation to the output of your php script.

The sed-based solutions will fail if the output of your PHP script contains forward slashes, and they will also substitute various escaped characters (`\n`s, `\t`s etc) that are present in the output of your PHP script, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: +1 The above is the right answer assuming you want to call php... once at the start of the script instead of every time {{KEY}} is found in the file. You should add an && after the script and before the mv though, and add the original file name at the end of the mv command.

Comment: @EdMorton The substitution is made by the shell upfront. So either way it's done only once.

Comment: @je4d The shell doesn't interpret the output of the command substitution. Escape character and `$` variables are taken as is. But you are right, that the output of `generate_key.php` is not allowed to have forward slashes `/`.

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah, I was being lazy about the `&&`s. Thanks for pointing out the missed arg to mv, fixed.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Right, the shell doesn't interpret it, the problem is that sed does. It's also not just the delimiter, note the output of `echo|sed 's/^/\t\n/'|hexdump -C`

Comment: @je4d Yes, you're right. But that's not different from awk. What did I miss?

Comment: @OlafDietsche not sure what you mean by "either way" - if you want to generate the key for every line, it's just a different solution than the one posted and involving `awk '{.."php -f generate_key.php" | getline key...}'`.

Comment: @je4d you're welcome and there's no need to escape the newline between && and mv.

Comment: @OlafDietsche - ah, I bet you thought I was comparing the awk solution to your posted sed solution and thought the sed solution would call `php...` for every line. No, I was just talking about the awk solution. This is not an appropriate application for sed at all.

Comment: @OlafDietsche you didn't miss anything.. I thought `-v VAR=VAL` passed a var verbatim, but the version of awk I've got to hand does evaluate escapes in the value, even though by my reading of the man page it shouldn't. It may be different for older versions of awk, I'm pretty sure I tested this to death in the past. Anyway, i'll change the answer to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
sed -e "s/{{KEY}}/`php -f generate_key.php`/g" app.config
```

This substitutes the replacement string with the output of the PHP script. If you want to modify app.config in place, add option `-i` to the command line

```
sed -i -e "s/{{KEY}}/`php -f generate_key.php`/g" app.config
```

As @je4d has observed, if the output of `generate_key.php` contains forward slashes `/`, you must use another delimiter instead, for example

```
sed -e "s;{{KEY}};`php -f generate_key.php`;g" app.config
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
cat app.config|sed 's/{{KEY}}/something/g'
```

Comment: `something` needs to come from `php -f generate_key.php` though.

Comment: Then put the above in a bash script with $1 instead of something, and call it within generate_key.php using system("yourscript.sh $something") where something is the variable you want.

Comment: That won't work as the $1 won't be expanded within single quotes. Also, drop the UUOC in `cat file | sed 'script'` and just dp `sed 'script' file`.